# RegExp Password Checker for Specific Lengths/Digit Counts

Tags: java, regex

Here's my RegExp checker which currently doesn't work:

```
String pattern = "(?=.*[0-9]{3})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]{1})(?=\\S+$).{5,15}";
```

Here are the parameters I cannot meet yet:

5-15 characters `{5,15}`

exactly 3 digits    `(?=.*[0-9]{3})`

Neither the character limit nor the digit check are working, and I can't find any examples for some reason. Where I am I going wrong? Clearly it's a placement issue, as I'm a total novice. Any help would be appreciated. The others (at least one upper/lowercase/special) I can meet, but these two simple pieces I'm still struggling with.

Comment: What is the password pattern? We need to know that before we try to fix your regex. You might also want to try regex'es and input strings online at [rubular](http://rubular.com/).

Comment: I'm only asking about the parts in the post, the 5-15 characters and exactly 3 digits. The rest of the pattern doesn't matter, as those portions of the code work correctly.

Comment: 3 integers total, consecutive doesn't matter. I "think" I have them set up as greedy, so consecutive integers don't matter?   asAS$5432 should fail due to the integer check, but does not.

Comment: Oh! So how do I change it? Where do I move it to? This is the crux of my problem, placement. Thank you!

Comment: How do I anchor it? Change `.` to `,`? I apologize for the simple questions, but I'm terrible with Google and can't find examples. && Thanks so much, I appreciate your time

Comment: I've moved comments to an answer and added a regex101 demo that should also explain it. (I don't think there is anything specific to java's regex processing here)

Comment: Since you’ve tagged this with [tag:java], do yourself—and future maintenance developers—a favor, and use a simple loop instead of this coercion of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

For three digits checking add this anywhere in your regex as you are using positive lookahead.

```
(?=^([^0-9]*[0-9]){3}[^0-9]*$)
```

For 5-15 digit check add this one:

```
(?=^.{5,15}$)
```

You can use the regex on the site https://regex101.com/ and it will give you the explanation on the right hand side.

Comment: Oh, grouping the `[^0-9]*[0-9]` is a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thanks so much for the website! You and chris85 answered my question, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]{3}` is 3 consecutive integers. To allow three integers somewhere in the string you need to check for each integer part.

```
(?=^[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*$)
```

`.{5,15}` is 5 to 15 characters but that is anywhere in the string, to have it affect the whole string that needs to be anchored. So your full expression should be:

```
^(?=^[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]{1})(?=\\S+$).{5,15}$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/UVK7ev/1